# Конвертация пути в файловой системе в url адрес в браузере

Tags: javascript, php, html

возникла такая проблема. У меня есть форма, с помощью которой можно загрузить и отправить изображение в базу данных, а на другой странице запросом получить путь до файла и отобразить его.
Но при попытке получить путь до изображения, находящегося у меня на компьютере, я получил следующее (C:\fakepath\wcAQ8zUI4Ts.jpg). По такому пути понятно, что изображение не отобразится на другой странице. Как мне преобразовать этот путь в url адрес, чтобы загружаемая картинка могла отобразиться в браузере? Мне нужно, чтобы при регистрации пользователь мог выбрать любую картинку с любой папки на компьютере и загрузить ее, а на другой странице получить свое изображение(Скрин текущий прилагаю)[image: Макет и текущий вывод адреса картинки]

Comment: Никак, это сделано в целях защиты приватности пользователя. После загрузки отдавайте загруженную картинку со своего сайта и не возитесь с локальными путями.

Comment: Если у Вас уже _"есть форма, с помощью которой можно загрузить и отправить изображение в базу данных"_, то зачем Вам еще пытаться _получить путь до изображения, находящегося на компьютере_? Загружайте изображение из вышеупомянутой базы данных.

Comment: На одной странице есть секция, в которой выводятся данные о пользователе и его комментарии. На второй странице есть форма регистрации пользователя. При регистрации пользователь может поставить себе аву выбрать какую нибудь картинку с компа. Так вот, в момент регистрации мне нужно получить адрес до картинки, чтобы потом загрузить этот адрес в базу данных, чтобы потом на условной первой странице с комментариями получить данные пользователя (в том числе и адрес картинки) и вывести все это дело на страницу. Сейчас при регистрации у меня не получается получить адрес, у меня он как на скрине.

Comment: Вот так примерно точное описание задания должно быть